# Display products from 2 categories in woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce I need to display products that are members of 2 categories. I am using the following code:

```
     <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 200, 'product_cat' =>         'Washington', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
         while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
```

I would like to display products which are members of both the categories "Washington" and "Small Single"

I do not want to display all products from "Washington", then all products from "Small Single", I would like to display all products which are members of both categories

How would I amend the above code to include the category "Small Single"?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a resolution to this?  The answer below does not work from my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with `category__and` parameter.

1) USE `Category IDs` of `"Washington" and "Small Single"`

2) In your `$args` Adjust below parameter.(I assume `Washington catId = 2` and `Small Single CatID = 6`)

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
```

3) It will only display Products contained in Both category.

I hope, It will help you!

Comment: I would love for a little more information as I am trying to implement this solution but unsuccessfully. Where do I put this code? Is this done by creating custom page template with an added woocommerce loop or do you somehow call it out? If I want to have different combination of categories on different pages would I need to created a dedicated page template for each one?

Comment: As far as I know, `product_cat` must be used to identify WooCommerce products by their category, and the slug must be used.  The standard `WP_Query` `cat` and `category__and` will not work in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same requirement, turned out to be very simple

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 200,
        'product_cat'    => 'washington+small-single',
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;
?>
```